# Rails testing Basic Auth header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

Please I need help on how to write controller test for a rails application. I want to validate the user using Basic Auth, where the header information is encoded in base64. When I write the test, for some reason it gives 404 error even when the details seem correct.

What I'm trying to achieve is whenever you call a specific page you have to be authorize to view the page. Please find below my sample test

```
test "Basic auth login" do

    au_headers = {"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" => "Basic #{Base64.encode64('sammy@dayqqq.com:0123456AHGDR67890292812345645564')}"}
    get sample_item_url(),params: {}, as: :json, headers: au_headers
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Please will appreciate any help that can be provided

Comment: Can you please edit the question and include your code with the proper formatting? You just need to copy the raw text into the question and press the `{}` button to indent it by four spaces.

Comment: what is `sample_item_url`? 404 error means the endpoint is not found, not that you're unauthorized.

Comment: sample_item_url is the endpoint am trying to fetch data from. When I try it using postman it works. I just don't understand why the test is failing

Comment: Please, open second terminal tab, run 'tail -f log/test.log`, run the test in first tab and add server log to the question

Comment: Thanks @Vasilisa I was able to see error message from the log file and fixed it.

Comment: @OseAgbadu, happy that it helped! It would be great if you add the log to the question and add your answer. It will be very helpful for someone with the same problem

Comment: The path URL was wrong. It requires some form of id. It was suppose to be get sample_item_url(userid).